# JMeter: Total size of data sent and received

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I use JMeter for API performance testing. One requirement I have is to send a specific size of data during the test (e.g., 10 TB).

I want to display (and save to log) the **total size of sent data and total size of received data** from all samplers.

Apparently, the values are collected, since the Summary report shows the average bytes. Also, I can see the sent and received data size per request in "View Results in Table".

Is there any simple way to pick the total size for sent and received data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter should save it by default in its [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)

[image]

so just open the .jtl results file (which is a normal CSV file) using [MS Excel](https://www.office.com/launch/Excel) or equivalent and sum all the values from `bytes` and `sentBytes` columns - it will give you the number of all inbound and outbound bytes which should be exactly you're looking for.

If you don't see these columns - make sure that `jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes` and `jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes` [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization) are set to `true`. All settings which control what's being stored in the .jtl results file along with their default values are available under [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) user manual entry.

Also the values can be checked in [jmeter.properties file](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.properties#L491-L576)

Comment: I think Excel will have trouble consuming/opening large files

Comment: Thanks, @DmitriT. I wanted to avoid summing up all request results and was wondering how to do that easier and automatically. The number of lines would be an issue for excel, but I can resolve it with a simple Python script.

Comment: I ended up with a Python script using Pandas, which easily allows making any calculations from the JTL file.